# How can I merge to arrays together if one value is a number?

Tags: php, arrays

I am merging two arrays (with values from the mySQL database) together:

```
$animals = array_merge($cat_array, $dog_array);
```

for `$cat_array` I get this result:

```
array(3) { ["WX81A846YZ8P"]=> string(1) "1" ["WX81A846YZ"]=> string(1) "1" [123]=> string(1) "1" }
```

and for `$dog_array`I get this result:

```
array(1) { ["WX81A846YU"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

for `$animals` I get this result:

```
array(4) { ["WX81A846YZ8P"]=> string(1) "1" ["WX81A846YZ"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" ["WX81A846YU"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

As you see, on the position, where there should be `123` there is a `0`. So why is it not working if I have only numbers in the array and how can I fix this?

Comment: try concatenating `$animals = $cat_array + $dog_array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `+`

```
$animals = $cat_array + $dog_array;
```

> Note:If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the `+` array union operator
>
> **Values in the input array with `numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.`**

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Thank you! Great! That is working. So simple. And why doesn't it work with `array_merge`? And why does anyone needs `array_merge` then?

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!